# AGV free space navigation in AnyLogic

Tags: java, algorithm, anylogic

I am a mechatronic engineer and I am currently working on my master thesis regarding the simulation of a particular AGV with a sprecific algorithm for the free space navigation.

Where can I find the free space algorithm used in AnyLogic?
Can I modify it?

Thanks
Luca

Answer (score 0):

you can't change the algorithm for AGVs if you use the material handling library since the algorithm is internal and untouchable.

But with agent based you can use your own algorithms freely and do whatever you want, so use that.